# including python package dependecy as an executable

Tags: python

Currently my python package does not have a dependency on the wmi package and it can be easily installed via

```
pip install mypackage
```

If I add a dependency on the wmi package, this will likely fail since when I try installing wmi through pip, I encounter errors since I do not have visual studio 2008 installed...and I only managed to get it installed using the binary distribution.
Is it possible for me to include and install the binary release of wmi in my package?

The main concern is that if people fail to install my package via the pip command, they just avoid using my package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to consider is **why** are you considering adding the `wmi` package - since it is MS-Windows specific if you use it, or anything depending on it, your package will also be MS-Windows specific.

Are there other ways to achieve what you are trying to do that remain cross platform? If not and you really ***have to*** use it then you could include a prerequisite statement in the documentation, and ideally in `setup.py`, telling people that they need to have an installed & working copy of wmi, hopefully with a pointer to the binary distributions.

The other way to go - if you are on a late enough version of python - is to build and distribute your package as [python wheels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel). Since wheels allow the inclusion of C package elements without relying on the presence of a compiler on the target system - see [pep-0427](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) & [here](http://pythonwheels.com/) for some more information.

### Creating Wheels:

*You need to be running python2 > 2.6 or python3, pip >= 1.4 and setuptools >= 0.8.*

Basically, assuming that you have a setup.py that will create your, (source), distribution for upload to pip with:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

then you can create a binary distribution that should contain all the dependencies of your package for your current python version with:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This will build a distribution wheel that includes the .pyc files and the binary files from the required packages.

But - you need to do this once for each version of python that you are planning of supporting, ([virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) is magic for this), and on each platform if you are also planning on supporting 64 bit or mac. Unless, of course, you manage to make a **pure python** package that will run, without 2to3, under both python 2 & 3 in which case you can build a universal wheel - obviously you can not do this if you require .c extensions.

For more information on wheels see [Wheel - Read The Docs](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks. My app is windows-only on purpose. wmi = windows management instrumentation. I do know that I can make my package without the wmi package which is probably what I better do. About python-wheels, it would be nice if you could post more concrete info/examples please.